# Fully reference a worksheet by codename

Tags: excel, vba

When I reference Excel worksheets using the CodeName property, how do I fully qualify them including the workbook reference?

I want to guard against a scenario with two different workbooks open and two sheets having the same CodeName. I use `ThisWorkbook` because I want to reference the workbook the code is running from.

I imagine something like this:

```
Dim tgWs As Worksheet
Set tgWs = ThisWorkbook.WsSummary
tgWs.Cells(1,1).Value = "Test"
```

where `WsSummary` is the sheet's codename.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Referring to a sheet by its codename always implies the sheet in `ThisWorkbook`, i.e. the workbook that contains the code you are executing.

There seems to be no straightforward way to fully qualify a sheet in a different workbook using its codename.

This function will help you do this:

```
Function GetSheetWithCodename(ByVal worksheetCodename As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
    Dim iSheet As Long
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' mimics the default behaviour
    For iSheet = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If wb.Worksheets(iSheet).CodeName = worksheetCodename Then
            Set GetSheetWithCodename = wb.Worksheets(iSheet)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iSheet
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
GetSheetWithCodename("Sheet1", Workbooks("Book2")).Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet1 in Book2"
GetSheetWithCodename("Sheet1", ActiveWorkbook).Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet1 in ActiveWorkbook"
GetSheetWithCodename("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet1 in ThisWorkbook"
```

Note that the last line is equivalent to simply saying:

```
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet1 in ThisWorkbook"
```

because, as mentioned above, referring to a sheet by its codename always imply the sheet in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I got error using this function on my Mac "Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Comment: `CallByName(wb, worksheetCodename, vbGet) ` should also work?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by adding the second Workbook as a reference, and calling the workbook by the VBA Project name.

Obviously, it's a good idea to *change* the VBA project name from the default 'VBAProject'!

I tested this by creating two new workbooks each with one sheet, with a value of 1 or 2 in cell A1. The VBA projects were named 'Proj1' and 'Proj2', and the worksheets' CodeNames were left as 'Sheet1'.

This is the code I used:

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print Proj1.Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
    Debug.Print Proj2.Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Yielding an output of:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Cool, I had no idea this was possible! But how do you get the VBA project from the workbook reference?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty cool! Your answer is better though, it avoids having to programmatically add a reference, where you might not know the VB project name...

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets can be referred to by their codename when the code is in the same workbook so fully qualifying is not necessary. You can't refer to another workbooks sheet by codename directly unless you loop each sheet and check the codename

so this is enough without needing to create a variable

```
with WsSummary
  .Cells(1,1).Value = "Test"
end with
```

Answer (score -1):

`Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet1 in ThisWorkbook"` without the `ThisWorkBook` prefix works fine without any extra methods

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws  as worksheet

Set wb = "Your Workbook full path and name"

For each ws in wb.worksheets
    If ws.codename = "Your Codename" then exit for
    next ws
```

`ws` will now contain the reference to the worksheet in other workbook with the desired codename with no user changeable dependencies

Hope this helps