# How does object focus work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Worksheet and Workbook objects can have their properties accessed in two ways.

1. Explicitly ➔ `Sheet1.cells(1,2)`
2. Implicitly ➔ `Cells(1,2)`

What I'm curious about is how does VBA know which object to use when a property is called implicitly? And are there more objects that are compatible with these implicit calls?

Here is a simple experimentation I threw together, it shows some cases where object focus changes and when it doesn't:

```
'Sheet1 has 2 row in column A
'Sheet2 has 5 rows in column A
Sub test()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Sheet1

    'focus is set when a sheet is called directly
    row1 = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'focus is set when a sheet is called through reference
    row2 = obj.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'focus is not set by with
    With Sheet2
        row3 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'output = 5 : 2 : 2
    MsgBox row1 & " : " & row2 & " : " & row3
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `With` use is incorrect - should be `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` - note the leading periods

Comment: Thanks, but that was actually on purpose. I was trying to see if the focus to sheet2 would be switched simply by the with statement itself.

Comment: Then that would explain why it didn't do anything ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Excel object references work like this:
`Workbook -> Worksheet -> Range`

If you leave out the previous node, Excel substitutes the "Active" object for the omitted ones.  Examples:
`Sheet1.Cells(1,1)` is the same as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)`
`Cells(1,1)` is the same as `ActiveWorksheet.Cells(1,1)`

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(1,1)` is [not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25203416/11683) as `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)`. It is the same as `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(1,1)`. As opposed to `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)`, which *is* the same as `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)`.

Comment: I just did a test, it seems that "ActiveSheet" is always set to the worksheet that is being displayed, even if you just called another sheet in the vba code

Comment: @Alter, calling a sheet does not make it active.  The sheet has to be activated/selected to be "Active"