# Get a sheet's codename using the sheet's name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write something where the user inputs the tab name of a worksheet in Excel and uses the tab name to get the sheet's codename before continuing through the code.

Comment: What good is a string var assigned to the worksheet's codename going to do? You cannot use the string like `strSheet1.Cells(1, 1)` or `Worksheets(strSheet1)` or really for anything else I can think of. You might be better to retrieve the ordinal index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25203173/1188513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Dim ShtCodeName As String

ShtCodeName = Worksheets("YourSheetName").CodeName
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it returned as a Worksheet that I can then use with commands like: ShtCodeName.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: @Logic `CodeName` is just a `String`. `Worksheets("YourSheetName")` gets you the worksheet object you're after, so `Set sheet = Worksheets("YourSheetName")` and then you can do `sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks!