# VBA Codename Reference

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I wish to reference my worksheets via codenames as part of a longer vba code - the current code I have is:

Works correctly:

```
If wb.Sheets("stage 1").Visible = xlVeryHidden Or wb.Sheets("stage 1").Visible = xlHidden Then wb.Sheets("Stage 1").Visible = True
```

Which I want to change to the below - "Stage 1" = Sheet8 within my excel file

```
If wb.Sheet8.Visible = xlVeryHidden Or wb.Sheet8.Visible = xlHidden Then wb.Sheet8.Visible = True
```

However upon changing the code it provides a runtime error 438.

Can someone advise how I can overcome this issue or where my code is incorrect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `wb.` parts. `Sheet8` is a variable and not a property of `wb`.

Comment: Presumably `wb` is defined as `ThisWorkbook`? If so, you can remove it and your code should work.

Comment: You could shorten that code to just `Sheet8.Visible = True`.  If the final result is that you want the sheet visible then just make it visible no matter the current state.

Comment: Thanks this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a sheet within VBA is the `codeName`

If the sheet it part of `ThisWorkbook` (that is the workbook where you code lives in), you can access it in your code like it is a variable (remove `wb.`)

```
   Sheet8.Visible = xlVeryHidden Or Sheet8.Visible = xlHidden Then Sheet8.Visible = True
```

However, if you want to access a sheet from a different workbook, you have to loop over all sheets to find it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203416/7599798

Answer (score -2):

What you will need to do is use:

```
    Dim Sht8 As Worksheet
    Set Sht8 = wb.Sheets("stage 1")
```

You should try not use `Sheet8` as the sheet objects inside the Excel WorkBook VBA project are using names such as `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and  `Sheet3` for the initial sheet name.

Comment: I'd agree in part with this - you shouldn't leave the sheets code name as `Sheet8`, the same as you wouldn't leave the tab name as `Sheet8`. Much better to change it in the sheet properties to something like `shtStage1`.  But, much better to use the codename rather than the tab name as the tab name can be changed by the user, while the codename can't.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook agreed, we need to be descriptive with our naming of Variable. Do you think was my answer worthy of a #DownVote?

Comment: I do - although I didn't down vote it.  `Sheet8` is the codename for the sheet and as you say in your answer - `sheet objects inside Excel are using names such as Sheet1....`.  The OP was trying to reference the sheet object using that name, while your answer was to reference the tab name which can be changed by the user.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Good Stuff, at least I learnt something, I never thought about a user changing sheet names which will then cause a error when running a bit of code.